# Custom view - a subclass of uiview cannot be resized

Tags: ios, swift

It must be a simple thing but I couldn't find a clue,

I am having a imageview and trying a scribbling view which is a subclass of  UIview on top of it to allow scribbling. All works fine except for resizing the scribbling view, it occupies the whole screen all the time I couldn't make it smaller.

```
class ScribbleView: UIView
{
    let backgroundLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()

    required init()
    {
       // super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer1)
        layer.masksToBounds = true

    }



class HermiteScribbleView: ScribbleView, Scribblable
{

    required init() {
        print ("calling parent")
        super.init()

    }

}
```

/** main code **/

```
let hermiteScribbleView = HermiteScribbleView()
hermiteScribbleView.backgroundColor = .red

      //  imgView.autoresizesSubviews = true
      //  hermiteScribbleView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]


    //once this is done, hermieScribbleView is always stretched to full width and height no matter what I try
        imgView.addSubview(hermiteScribbleView)
```

Comment: If you log the frames of both imgView and hermiteScribbleView, immediately after `addSubview()`, what results do you get?

Comment: Assuming two things: (1) You aren't using auto layout, and (2) you've stripped out some code, including setting the frames on certain views/layers that may matter. I also can't quite grasp the complete view hierarchy, so this may be off base. But let's say your ScribbleView, a UIView, is a subview of a UIImageView (which your description seems to say)... why not just make the whole thing a custom UIImageView and then in layoutSubviews set the frames to be the same? You ca even get fancy and set things once if needed.

Comment: got it, I had to initialize the ScribbleView after viewdidload() not while declaring property, I need it as a property though to access it in other methods, but thats another thing I will look around, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: add layoutIfNeeded() after adding subview

Comment: @dfd, yes finally have got it working from what you have said.

Answer (score 1):

What i guess from above information is that, you might be using the frame of `UIImageView` to set the frame of `UIView`. you need to set the size of `UIView` same as the size of `UIImage`.

- `imgImageView.image.size`

and secondly set the centre of `UIView` same as centre of `UIImageView`.
Hope this will work.