# Initialize a class in viewDidLoad and assign it to member variable

Tags: ios, swift

I have a customview, a subclass of `UIView` but when I try to initialise as a class property it gives me non-desired behavior, which I have mentioned here,
[Custom view - a subclass of uiview cannot be resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539642/custom-view-a-subclass-of-uiview-cannot-be-resized?noredirect=1)

```
class SignViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    let hermiteScribbleView = HermiteScribbleView()
}
```

but works fine in `viewDidLoad()` though,

I need to access `hermiteScribbleView` it in other methods of `SignViewController`

I tried like this but no avail,

```
class SignViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    var hermiteScribbleView:HermiteScribbleView?
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let hermiteScribbleView1 = HermiteScribbleView()
        hermiteScribbleView = hermiteScribbleView1
    }
}
```

Here is one of many places where I am using the property

```
func landscapeOps(){
    hermiteScribbleView?.triggerLandscape()
    if(hermiteScribbleView?.currentStage == 0 ) {
        hermiteScribbleView?.backgroundLayer2.isHidden = true
        hermiteScribbleView?.backgroundLayer1.isHidden = false
    }else if (hermiteScribbleView?.currentStage == 1) {
        hermiteScribbleView?.LineLayer.isHidden = true
        hermiteScribbleView?.backgroundLayer1.isHidden = true
        hermiteScribbleView?.backgroundLayer2.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: why is it so critical to initialize it as a class property?

Comment: I have edited the question where it shows one of the times I am using the property, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: i would recommend to use lazy initializer. as I remember, swift has lazy vars built in feature. also, you can always write a classic lazy function initializer.

Comment: you should create a protocol/delegate, your high level class should not edit that view, just tell it to change or call method prepared for that in hermiteScribbleView

Comment: lazy seems to be the right way to go, it only initalize the property once it get called the first time in code